# What unit of measurement does setMinimumWidth() use in an android view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I understand the difference between the various measurement units used in android layouts (dp, sp, px, etc), but it's not clear to me which unit is used when setting the width via java code.

Which unit does `setMinimumWidth(int minWidth)` use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pixels. All values set by code are in pixels. If you want different values, you must compute pixels using getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density to do conversion (or using other values from DisplayMetrics).

Comment: >>"All values set by code are in pixels" all but  TextView.setTextSize(int sizeSp);